Problema con tasa de impuestos dinamica en WooCommerce
Tengo un problema, cree una tienda en woocommerce la cual es privada, es decir solo unos pocos clientes tienen acceso a la tienda, y cada cliente tiene su usuario y contraseña para acceder, debido a que cada cliente tiene distintos precios en los productos.
Pero por lo mismo, cada cliente tiene una tasa de impuestos distinta, por lo que la solución que idee fue establecer varias tarifas estándar de impuesto, y con código de php manipular que según el id del usuario logueado, aplicar cierta tarifa estándar.
Este codigo me funcionaba muy bien, pero ahora luego de realizar la migración de la tienda a un nuevo hosting, este codigo ya no me funciona, y aplica por defecto siempre la 'standard_rate_1' a todos los usuarios, pese a desactivar el fragmento de codigo, siempre aplica esa tarifa estandar.
¿Me podrian ayudar? O sugerirme como puedo hacerlo mejor.
Se los re agradeceria
// Aplicar tasas de impuestos segun el ID del usuario logueado

function wctbu_apply_tax_rates($taxes, $order) {
if (!$order || !is_a($order, 'WC_Order')) {
    return $taxes; // No se puede calcular impuestos
}

$user_id = $order->get_customer_id();

// Definir aquí los IDs de usuario y las tasas de impuestos correspondientes
$user_tax_rates = array(
    '2' => 'standard_rate_1', // User ID => Tax rate slug
    '4' => 'standard_rate_2', // User ID => Tax rate slug
    '7' => 'standard_rate_1', // User ID => Tax rate slug
    // Agregar más usuarios y tasas de impuestos aquí según sea necesario
);

if (isset($user_tax_rates[$user_id])) {
    $tax_rate_slug = $user_tax_rates[$user_id];
    $tax_rate = WC_Tax::get_rate_percent($tax_rate_slug);
    $subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();
    $tax_amount = ($subtotal * $tax_rate) / 100;
    $taxes += $tax_amount; // Agregar el impuesto adicional al total de impuestos
    $order->set_total_tax($taxes); // Establecer el total de impuestos en el pedido
}
return $taxes;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_order_amount_tax', 'wctbu_apply_tax_rates', 10, 2);


Este codigo me funcionaba muy bien, pero ahora luego de realizar la migración de la tienda a un nuevo hosting, este codigo ya no me funciona... 1) Depura tu código, por ejemplo verificando si es que se está cumpliendo esto if (!$order || !is_a($order, 'WC_Order')) {. Eso implica también buscar en el log de errores o bien activar el modo debug de Wordpress. 2) Revisa qué diferencias hay entre el entorno anterior y el actual, por ejemplo, versión de PHP, de Wordpress, de WooCommerce, etc. 3) Asegúrate de tener instalada la última versión de WooCommerce.
